# Need to vertically align an element with it's sibling element based on scaling due to window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I have an element that always needs to be vertically aligned with it's sibling element no matter what the window width is. I'm hoping to be able to do this with CSS, but seems like it may need to be done with JavaScript. If that's the case, jQuery is okay and it just needs to support modern browsers (IE 11+).

The tricky part about this is that it needs to be at 50% of the image and not the entire container.

[image]

Please note: the markup or styling cannot be changed on the parent or sibling of div.icon.

https://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/srp7g2cf/

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.icon {
  height: 8vw;
  width: 8vw;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
body {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list clearfix">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x750">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et hymenaeos elit orci, rutrum dolor magna pellentesque ante euismod magna, sodales turpis quos class condimentum. Integer in vel etiam. Etiam pellentesque nibh phasellus sed, eget ipsum enim sed in et at, non ligula quis
      egestas sed quis. Lectus vitae, lobortis vestibulum maecenas auctor lorem eros, luctus vitae aliquam aliquam ipsum ligula nascetur, habitasse eu lectus imperdiet leo. Ut est fusce class conubia nunc felis, proin aliquam vitae nunc accumsan orci.
      A eu erat in.</li>
    <li>Ut in integer pulvinar maiores, mi sapien litora nunc ut, neque netus in ac. Et nullam, donec sapien laoreet, ullamcorper vestibulum et sed at arcu, erat scelerisque vehicula justo nam malesuada vehicula, per nibh nibh elit justo. Tempus omnis, mattis
      taciti cras a.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great flow chart showing how to center in every situation https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/. Also, this technique is pretty handy for vertically centering stuff, but won't work in every situation http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: Do you add the `.icon` by yourself? Are there any other elements int the`.slide` except from the `img`? Are there more images in the slider, and if they are, do they differ in height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in order to subtract half of the element's height from `top: 50%`:

```
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 4vw);
  height: 8vw;
  width: 8vw;
}
```

Of course you could also just displace the element using a negative margin equal to half of the element's height:

```
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -4vw;
  height: 8vw;
  width: 8vw;
}
```

Based on the comments, since you're using the [slick library](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), you would need to append the `.icon` element to the slider so that it is absolutely positioned *relative* to it.

You can listen to the `init` event and then append the icon accordingly:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/v2d2yv3x/)

```
$('.list').on('init', function(event, slick) {
  var $icon = $(this).closest('.container').find('.icon');
  $(this).append($icon);
});
```

Comment: calc is not crossbrowser, there is an another simpler way

Comment: @DenysKonoplin ... which is why I posted two options. However, `calc()` is supported in all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc .. plus the OP is already using viewport-percentage units, so I don't think support is an issue here.

Comment: Agreed, plus the question code uses `vw` which has similar browser support (i.e. no IE 8)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried out the code you posted on JSFiddle, but it's doing the same thing. The issue is due to having additional content beneath the image. I need the icon to always be at 50% of just the image (and exclude whatever elements are below it)

Comment: @Cofey Can you modify the HTML? If so, just move the `.icon` element into the `.slide` element and relatively position it -> https://jsfiddle.net/rx2LoLzh/

Comment: No, unfortunately, I cannot. I'm using Slick carousel and there can be many .slide elements.

Comment: @Cofey Okay, I updated my answer based on slick, here is an updated example as well -> https://jsfiddle.net/v2d2yv3x/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want the icon to be vertically centered, if so just set top and bottom to 0, and add margin: auto. see updated code below.

```
.icon {
  height: 8vw;
  width: 8vw;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: In addition, for future use, if you add left: 0 and right: 0: you will get absolutely centered element :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work due to the additional content that appears in a different sibling element.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jQuery.

just replace style for .icon with next:

```
.icon {
  height: 8vw;
  width: 8vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
.icon:before {
   background: blue;
  content: '';
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srp7g2cf/5/

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work due to the additional content that appears in a different sibling element.

Comment: hmmm it's really strange, can you make a jsfiddle link to see what you mean?

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/4uzko7xy/. Try changing the width of the HTML pane and note how the square always stays in the center of the entire container, instead of the center of the image.

Comment: just move icon to the slide and add position relative to slide
https://jsfiddle.net/jdz1333b/